# C++: GetPrivateProfileStringA - random values?

Tags: c++, winapi

Let me start off by saying it's been several years (over 8) since I have had to mess with C++. I am very rusty again and it looks like I'll have to start doing some side projects to get the hang of it.

I know this is really simple and I'm sure it's something very small that I am doing incorrectly... I am receiving garbage characters from my returned value and I can't figure out why. Maybe it has to do with my encoding? Not sure.

A simple function to retrieve the value from an INI file in Windows:

```
LPCTSTR getConfigValue(LPCTSTR key) {
    char retval[256];

    DWORD dw;
    if ((dw = GetPrivateProfileStringA("RLWELF", "DestinationIP", NULL, retval, 256, ".\\rlwelf.ini")) > 0) {    
        return NULL;
    }

    OutputDebugStringA(retval);

    return (LPCTSTR)retval;
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please turn on or up your warning level: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/59209dc77f686bdf (note: type alias incorrect for simplification). If this is VS and it doesn't warn about these period, then my bad, but that would be really sad to hear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
return (LPCTSTR)retval;
```

You are returning the address of a local variable. That local variable is destroyed as soon as the function returns. It is therefore undefined behaviour for the caller to de-reference the returned pointer. You would need to:

1. Have the caller provide a buffer into which the function can write.
2. Have the function allocate memory on the heap. The caller would need to deallocate it.
3. Start using the C++ standard library and return a `std::string`.

Option 3 is head and shoulders above the others.

Beyond that the cast is dubious. I suspect that you are compiling with `UNICODE` defined. Which means that `LPCTSTR` expands to `const wchar_t*`. That in turn means that your cast would erroneous. You would be lying to the compiler. The compiler will always exact its revenge when you lie to it.

You should get out of the habit of using `TCHAR`. Compile with `UNICODE` defined and use the platform native UTF-16 character encoding for text.

Finally, `GetPrivateProfileString` is a really ancient API that is not encouraged to be used nowadays. The documentation says:

> This function is provided only for compatibility with 16-bit Windows-based applications.

If you must use INI files, then use a good C++ library. This will result in a code writing experience that is many orders of magnitude cleaner, safer and quicker.

Answer (score 1):

`retval` is a local variable, it is destroyed at the end of the function, so when you try to return it, the caller receives a pointer to garbage.

Instead, you could malloc a buffer and return it, take an output pointer in argument, or return a unique_ptr to a buffer.